# Working with Big Files with Sql Sever from Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I was working on a product where i have to write script in python for fetching big files(Around 1-1.5 GB) and do some processing and finally uploading into some other tables multiple times. I wrote a code for the same, but i feel it is taking way too much time for processing my code, i found that mostly it stuck when i am uploading files in to the tables, i want optimize the process around uploading and fetching the file from DB, I need help from you guys on that.

My function for Creating connection with Database:

```
def create_sqlalchemy_engine(server,db,username,passwrd,driver):
try:
    engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://{user}:{pw}@{server}/{db}?driver={drivr}"
                       .format(user=username,
                                server=server,
                               pw=passwrd,
                               db=db,
                               drivr=driver))
except Exception as e:
raise e
return engine
```

For Fetching File:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
          SELECT *
          FROM {}''').format(Table_A)
```

For Uploading:

```
df.to_sql(table_name)
```

Comment: Instead of mentioned just the file size `(Around 1-1.5 GB)`, you can also include the number of rows it's fetching/reading or writing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reading SQL Query: Use `chunksize` param to speed up.

> If specified, return an iterator where chunksize is the number of rows to include in each chunk.

[documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query) on available params:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('''
          SELECT *
          FROM {}''', engine, chunksize=1000).format(Table_A)
```

2. Writing to SQL: You can speed up writing to the SQL database in two steps.

   - Set `fast_executemany=True` in `create_engine`, [link to the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#mssql-pyodbc-fastexecutemany). Make sure you're using SQLAlchemy 1.3 or later.
   - Change your `df.to_sql` code to the following:

```py
df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, index=False, if_exists="append", schema="dbo", chunksize=1000)
```

remove `index=False` if needed from above. The meaning of those params can be found in the [documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql).

Comment: file By file size I meant to say around 5-8 million records.  You are suggesting Adding fast_executemany = True parameter would speedup the process when writing. Thanks

Comment: Yes, also using `chunksize` param for writing in chunks. Let me know the results after applying above changes.